# Why is the UIScrollView not scrolling at the top

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement a UIScrollView with several different views inside.

Here is the hierarchy:

- Main View

  - Scroll View
  - Container View1

    - Container View2

      - View1
      - View2 (top space to View1=1, bottom space to View3=1, trailing/leading space to superview=0, proportional height to Container View2 = 0.2 multiplier)
      - View3
      - View4
      - View5

(I needed to add Container View1 because I was copying and pasting from another view controller and didn't want to lose all of the constraints)

When I scroll, only the bottom scrolls and all of the sizes of the inside views change, but the top is locked in place.
[image]

What I would like is to have the top scroll upwards and all of the views remain the same shape.

All views and constraints are entirely implemented in the storyboard.
Each of the View1 to View5 have the same constraints.

Comment: The container view is helpful, make sure you added top/bottom/leading/trailing constraint between the container view and the scroll view, then that the constraint between all the view determine an exact height and width for the container view based only on what’s inside not outside, especially the container view, for the proportional constraint try to make it relative to the scroll view or the VC main view not the container view